# MatLab using Fixed Point method to find a root

Tags: matlab

I wanna find a root for the following function with an error less than 0.05%

```
f=  3*x*tan(x)=1
```

In the MatLab i've wrote that code to do so:

```
clc,close all

syms x;

x0 = 3.5
f= 3*x*tan(x)-1;
df = diff(f,x);

while (1)

x1 =  1 / 3*tan(x0)

%DIRV.. z= tan(x0)^2/3 + 1/3

er = (abs((x1 - x0)/x1))*100

if ( er <= 0.05)
    break;
end

x0 = x1;

pause(1)
end
```

But It keeps running an infinite loop with error 200.00 I dunno why.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while true`, as that's usually uncalled for and prone to getting stuck in infinite loops, like here. Simply set a limit on the `while` instead:

```
while er > 0.05
    %//your code
end
```

Additionally, to prevent getting stuck in an infinite loop you can use an iteration counter and set a maximum number of iterations:

```
ItCount = 0;
MaxIt = 1e5; %// maximum 10,000 iterations
while er > 0.05 & ItCount<MaxIt
    %//your code
    ItCount=ItCount+1;
end
```

Comment: There really isn't a functional difference between this and having a `break` in an identical `if` statement. If the error bound is never reached they're both going to loop infinitely.

Comment: @excaza I still think it's more clear to do it this way; I added an iteration counter to kill off infinite loops as well

Comment: I've done that but it's still giving me wrong error values, it must reach 0.5 but it doesn't... It gives these values at the end..

x1 =

    0.0047


er =

  199.9805

Comment: @MarcoV apparently your program does not converge to a small error.

Comment: I've done it using Newton Raphson method and it worked perfectly, that just happens when I use this Fixed Point method finding the root.

Answer (score 0):

I see four points of discussion that I'll address separately:

---

1. Why does the error seemingly saturate at 200.0 and the loop continue infinitely?

   The fixed-point iterator, as written in your code, is finding the root of `f(x) = x - tan(x)/3`; in other words, find a value of `x` at which the graphs of `x` and `tan(x)/3` cross.  The only point where this is true is `0`.  And, if you look at the value of the iterants, the value of `x1` is approaching `0`. Good.

   The bad news is that you are also dividing by that value converging toward `0`.  While the value of `x1` remains finite, in a floating point arithmetic sense, the division works but may become inaccurate, and `er` actually goes `NaN` after enough iterations because `x1` underflowed below the smallest denormalized number in the IEEE-754 standard.

   Why is `er` 200 before then?  It is approximately 200 because the value of `x1` is approximately 1/3 of the value of `x0` since `tan(x)/3` locally behaves as `x/3` a la its Taylor Expansion about `0`.  And `abs(1 - 3)*100 == 200`.

   Divisions-by-zero and relative orders-of-magnitude are why it is sometimes best to look at the absolute *and* relative error measures for *both* the values of the independent variable and function value.  If need be, even putting an extremely (relatively) small finite, constant value in the denominator of the relative calculation isn't *entirely* a bad thing in my mind (I remember seeing it in some numerical recipe books), but that's just a band-aid for robustness's sake that typically hides a more serious error.

---

2. This convergence is far different compared to the Newton-Raphson iterations because it has absolutely no knowledge of slope and the fixed-point iteration will converge to wherever the fixed-point is (forgive the minor tautology), assuming it does converge.  Unfortunately, if I remember correctly, fixed-point convergence is only guaranteed if the function is continuous in some measure, and `tan(x)` is not; therefore, convergence is not guaranteed since those pesky poles get in the way.

---

3. The function it appears you want to find the root of is `f(x) = 3*x*tan(x)-1`.  A fixed-point iterator of that function would be `x =  1/(3*tan(x))` or `x = 1/3*cot(x)`, which is looking for the intersection of `3*tan(x)` and `1/x`.  However, due to point number (2), those iterators still behave badly since they are discontinuous.

   A slightly different iterator `x = atan(1/(3*x))` should behave a lot better since small values of `x` will produce a finite value because `atan(x)` is continuous along the whole real line.  The only drawback is that the domain of `x` is limited to the interval (-pi/2,pi/2), but if it converges, I think the restriction is worth it.

---

4. Lastly, for any similar future coding endeavors, I do highly recommend @Adriaan's advice.  If would like a sort of compromise between the styles, most of my iterative functions are written with a semantic variable `notDone` like this:

   ```
   iter = 0;
   iterMax = 1E4;
   tol = 0.05;
   notDone = 0.05 < er &  iter < iterMax;
   while notDone
           %//your code
           iter    = iter + 1;
           notDone = 0.05 < er &  iter < iterMax;
   end
   ```

You can add flags and all that jazz, but that format is what I frequently use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the code below achieves what you are after using Newton's method for the convergence. Please leave a comment if I have missed something.

```
% find x: 3*x*tan(x) = 1

f    = @(x) 3*x*tan(x)-1;
dfdx = @(x) 3*tan(x)+3*x*sec(x)^2;

tolerance = 0.05; % your value?
perturbation = 1e-2;
converged = 1;

x = 3.5;
f_x = f(x);

% Use Newton s method to find the root
count = 0;
err = 10*tolerance; % something bigger than tolerance to start
while (err >= tolerance)
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 1e3)
        converged = 0;
        disp('Did not converge.');
        break;
    end

    x0 = x;

    dfdx_x = dfdx(x);
    if (dfdx_x ~= 0)
        % Avoid division by zero
        f_x = f(x);
        x = x - f_x/dfdx_x;
    else
        % Perturb x and go back to top of while loop
        x = x + perturbation;
        continue; 
    end

    err = (abs((x - x0)/x))*100;
end

if (converged)
    disp(['Converged to ' num2str(x,'%10.8e') ' in ' num2str(count) ...
          ' iterations.']);
end
```